# calling a method using prototype

Tags: javascript

```
<script>     
  var Kevin = function(){   
       this.name = 'kevin'
  }          
  Kevin.prototype.getKevin = function(){          
       alert(this.name);        
  }            
  Kevin.prototype.getKevin();

  function John(){
     this.name = 'john'
  }      
  John.getStaticJohn = function(){
     alert(this.name);    
  }

  John.prototype.getJohn();
  John.getStaticJohn();

</script>
```

1. Why is that i am getting `undefined` in both the cases when calling
   the method using prototype.
2. When i try to call the static method in John class, it prints the
   output perfectly.

Comment: `Object.prototype` just allows you to extend the object from outside of it. Calling it still relies on an instance of said object being defined first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting `undefined` because the prototype has no "name" property.  Note also that your call to "getStaticJohn()" does not in fact "work perfectly" - it alerts "John" with a capital "J" because it's accessing the "name" property of the function object "John".

When you call a method via an expression of the form `something.functionName`, then the value of `this` inside the function will always be the value of `something`.  Thus when you call

```
John.prototype.getJohn();
```

the value of `this` inside the "getJohn()" function will be `John.prototype`, and not any instance constructed by the "John()" constructor.

If you add this:

```
John.prototype.name = "John's prototype";
```

then your call to `John.prototype.getJohn()` will alert something other than `undefined`.

Comment: Can you lead me to a nice article on prototype where i can understand the concept fully.

Answer (score 4):

If you wanted to call the methods from the constructor, you would need to create an anonymous instance:

```
(new Kevin).getKevin(); // or new Kevin().getKevin()
```